# I don't like my job but my family members are forcing to continue this job. Don't know what to do

Tags: work-life-balance, fresher

After completing my college I joined in a company as SEO(Search Engine Optimizer) and worked for 2 years. In that Job I got lot of satisfaction because I love that Job. later I got an opportunity to work in an MNC as `.Net` developer as a FRESHER( So I lost my 2 years experience) and I got that job. But I don't know `.NET`. I have been here for 9 months but due to less interest in programming field I learned nothing. Also my first project is not related to .NET so I don't know `.NET`, After completing that project I got pure `.NET` project and I'm struggling a lot here. No one is helping since I have 9 months experience here. So I planned to relieve from here. But my parents are forcing me too continue here since I'm getting lot of pay and getting chance to go abroad. I don't how to handle this situation. I don't know how to balance work and life.

Comment: Do your parents know that you are unhappy with your job? I know how Indian parents are, but I would be *highly surprised* if they know how much you are suffering and yet insist on keeping you unhappy. Just telling them "I want to leave this job, I don't like it" isn't enough. Also, you say you have no interest in programming, but you also say you left an earlier job to take this .NET job. Something doesn't add up. Why did you take the job if you were not interested in it, especially when you already had a job?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is really a family problem, not a workplace one.

It sounds like you want to make your own decisions, and although you're from a culture which traditionally defers a lot of authority to one's parents, it's the only way you will be able to do what you want.

Either continue listening to them and stay in your current job, or explain to them that you wish to make your own decision and hope they will support you.

Not knowing your culture, I won't try to tell you whether this is a good idea or not, or whether it's likely to be effective or cause you other problems, but it's the only solution I can see. Likewise I won't attempt to push my own culture onto you, but I will state that I believe (on a personal level) the only way to be happy in life is to follow your OWN goals and ambitions.

Comment: Yes! you are correct.